# JSON to data structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I've never formally learned javascript, and I feel very much like I'm unaware of 'good' practice.

I'm working on [this](https://github.com/equalitytime/theopenvoicefactory) open source project, and in particular the code that converts the incoming JSON into a usable data structure in [this file](https://github.com/eQualityTime/TheOpenVoiceFactory/blob/master/templates/javascript/read_json.js)

The relevent function looks like this:

```
   function start() {
       key = "toppage";
       utterances = {};
       links = {};
       colours = {};
       icons = {};
       labels = {};
       slide_number = {};
       var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
       req.open("GET", "pageset.json");
       req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
       req.send(null);
       req.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
               var obj = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
               for (grid in obj.Grid) {
           console.log(obj.Grid[grid][0])
                   labels[obj.Grid[grid][0]] = obj.Grid[grid][1];
                   utterances[obj.Grid[grid][0]] = obj.Grid[grid][2];
                   links[obj.Grid[grid][0]] = obj.Grid[grid][3];
                   icons[obj.Grid[grid][0]] = obj.Grid[grid][4];
                   colours[obj.Grid[grid][0]] = obj.Grid[grid][5];
                   slide_number[obj.Grid[grid][0]] = obj.Grid[grid][6];
           if(obj.Grid[grid][6]==0){
            key=obj.Grid[grid][0]
            }
               }
               grid_size_rows = obj.Settings[0];
               grid_size_columns = obj.Settings[0];
               setup_messagewindow();
               setup_table();
               load_page(key);
           }
       };
       //TODO - needs an error message if the JSON doesn't load
   }
```

I have NO idea if this is a reasonable way to populate structures in javascript.  It works, but I feel like it could be a hell of a lot more elegant.  Any comments people have would be welcome.

Comment: Could you add a document from the response you're receiving? Also, this is not a complete code. Functions `setup_*()` are missing. CodeReview does not allow posting partial code with links to GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,you declare them without anything,so it's probably declared globally,this is not good,with this amount of variables in global.

Second of all,[ES6 Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
var [a,b,c,d,e]=arr;
console.log(a,b,c,d,e); // 1,2,3,4,5
```

Using the same way,

```
for (grid in obj.Grid) {
    var i=obj.Grid[grid][0];
    var [unused,labels[i], utterances[i], links[i], icons[i], colours[i], slide_number[i]]
    =obj.Grid[grid]
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Declare variables with `let` (if it gets reassigned) or `const` (if it never gets reassigned).
  I would recommend against using `var` nowadays. There are no use cases I know of where it is better than `let`.

  As far as I can see, all variables in your posted code can be declared `const`.
- Do not use `for (const entry in obj)` pattern for iterating keys. You use it here: `for (grid in obj.Grid)`.

  Modern alternatives:

  ```
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    // ...
  }

  for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    const value = obj[key]
    // ...
  }
  ```
- Use `===` for comparison, e.g. `req.status === 200`
- You could use the newer [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) as a replacement for `XMLHttpRequest`. In my opinion, this is worthwhile just for the Promise-driven code you get for free. For example, your `//TODO - needs an error message if the JSON doesn't load` can be expressed as `.catch(err => /* error handling */)` (note that fat arrow function syntax).
- Extract `"pageset.json"` into a constant: `const ASSET_JSON_ENDPOINT = "pageset.json"` and put it at the beginning of the function or even outside of the function in the outer scope of your

  - file or
  - module (ES6+ terminology) or
  - your Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)

  Generally, I would recommend using modules (with `import ... from ...` and `export ...` syntax). They supersede IIFEs.

  Also choose a better name than "asset" depending on the kind of data you're loading.
- Properly indent/auto-format your code.